# Divide rows within a group

Tags: sql-server

Suppose I have a table in which I observe traders' borrowing and lending behavior in certain instruments over time: For each trader, instrument and date, I observe *at most* two rows indicating a lending and borrowing amount. The row for lending (borrowing) is missing if there is no such activity. There is no restriction on the amounts except that they are all positive.

```
trader | instrument   | date        | type   | sum
A      | X            | 2020-01-01  | LEND   | 100
A      | X            | 2020-01-01  | BORR   | 50
A      | Y            | 2020-01-01  | LEND   | 50
A      | Y            | 2020-01-01  | BORR   | 150
```

I wish to process the data to obtain

```
trader | date        | result
A      | 2020-01-01  | 75
```

To obtain the trader and date specific result, compute for each instrument `min(100*BORR/LEND;100)` (with `min(x;y)` being the [minimum function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Minimum.html)) and then average over instruments. That is for the above example: `[min(100*50/100;100) + min(100*150/50;100)]/2 = 75`. I wish to drop any instrument in which a trader does not lend.

**My question**: How do I compute the minimum expression within an instrument?

My only idea is to construct an intermediate result

```
SELECT
    trader,
    instrument,
    CASE 
       WHEN SUM(CASE WHEN type='BORR' THEN sum ELSE 0 END)<SUM(CASE WHEN type='LEND' THEN sum ELSE 0 END)
       THEN 100*SUM(CASE WHEN type='BORR' THEN sum ELSE 0 END)/SUM(CASE WHEN type='LEND' THEN sum ELSE 0 END) 
       ELSE 100
    END AS result
GROUP BY
    trader,
    instrument,
    date
HAVING
    SUM(CASE WHEN type='LEND' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)=1
```

and subsequently average by trader and date.

However, this is more than ugly and slow due to the string comparison. This is problematic as I have around 30 Mio rows. This would be a two-liner in Pandas, however I do not have enough Memory for this computation. Thanks for your help.

Comment: In your expression `MIN(100*BORR/LEND,100)`,  I don't understand what the `COMMA 100` is for

Comment: It is the minimum function, e.g. `MIN(5,10)=5`.

Comment: ok I see what you mean, but this isnt valid SQL syntax so it was confusing. How many distinct instruments do you have ?

Comment: Yes, sorry about that. Unique number of instruments is in the low tens of thousands, however the majority of trades is based on only a few thousand instruments...

Comment: Can you edit your question so that the syntax of those `MIN()` functions make sense for us SQL Server guys?